# Duplicating the number of controlled systems

Tags: labview

I have a file that controls three pumps (pressure and temperature). I want to extend the number to six. Is there a quick way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Without any code I have no idea. Expand your question with more details (hardware, software).

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty: Just copy and paste the code to make two parallel while loops, then reconfigure the output channels to match the three new pumps. Depending on what you are doing this may be a bad idea. I think it's better to turn away from the computer for a while, dig out paper and pen and start thinking of what the new system would be like. Once there is a clear thought behind the redesign, the coding may come easier.